# show image and title , when button click in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, fetch

I want to show an image and a title when I click the button. I created a form to do it. It's only working to show "Title". Image is not showing. Here is the my code, please help me.

```js
function showImage()
    {
        document.getElementById('showTitle').innerHTML=document.getElementById('imgTitle').value;
        document.getElementById('showImage').innerHTML=document.getElementById('imagP').value;
    }
```

```html
<!-- Input Area-->

<input type="text" id="imgTitle"/>

<input type="file" id="imagP"/>

<button onclick="showImage()" >Show Image</button>


<!-- Show Image & Title-->

<p id="showTitle"></p>

<img src="" id="showImage">


<!-- JavaScript Code-->
```

Comment: Hey!, Clicking on show image button doing nothing when i run the snippet

Comment: (showImage).innerHTML - the `showImage` element is a an `img` - it doesn't have any inner HTML.  Perhaps you wanted `document.getElementById('showImage').src=`

Comment: @PrashantShah you have to give some value to form first. But as commented above, the issue is using value instead of src.

Comment: @E.Maggini Oh! I see value is used that's why it's showing nothing after selecting file.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `FileReader` to read the uploaded file.

```js
function showImage() {
  document.getElementById('showTitle').innerHTML=document.getElementById('imgTitle').value;
  var preview = document.querySelector('#showImage');
  var file    = document.querySelector('#imagP').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    preview.src = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="imgTitle"/>

<input type="file" id="imagP"/>

<button onclick="showImage()" >Show Image</button>


<!-- Show Image & Title-->

<p id="showTitle"></p>

<img src="" id="showImage">
```

Answer (score 0):

here is we use `fileChange` function on each time you change file.
and add style of display none to img tag where we want to show image, so we can show/hide image on `Show Image` button click.

```js
let file = null;

function showImage() {
  document.getElementById('showTitle').innerHTML = document.getElementById('imgTitle').value;
  const showImage = document?.getElementById('showImage');
  showImage.style?.display = 'block';
  showImage.src = window?.URL?.createObjectURL(file);
}
const fileChange = (fileObj) => {
  document.getElementById('showTitle').innerHTML = '';
  const showImage = document.getElementById('showImage');
  showImage.style.display = 'none';
  file = fileObj.target.files[0]
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    #editable {
      width: 400px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="imgTitle" />

  <input type="file" id="imagP" onchange="fileChange(event)" />

  <button onclick="showImage()">Show Image</button>


  <!-- Show Image & Title-->

  <p id="showTitle"></p>

  <img src="" id="showImage" style="display:none">

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to achieve it as below

```js
 function showImage()
    {
        document.getElementById('showTitle').innerHTML=document.getElementById('imgTitle').value;
        
        if(document.getElementById('imagP').files[0] != null) {
            document.getElementById('showImage').src=URL.createObjectURL(document.getElementById('imagP').files[0]);
        } else {
            alert("please select the image")
        }
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="imgTitle"/>

<input type="file" id="imagP"/>

<button onclick="showImage()" >Show Image</button>


<!-- Show Image & Title-->

<p id="showTitle"></p>

<img src="" id="showImage">
```